# Haskell - "How can I use "if" statement in "do" block properly?

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements, do-notation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell “do nothing” IO, or if without else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832828/haskell-do-nothing-io-or-if-without-else)

Something got wrong in these "easy" lines ...

```
action = do
    isdir <- doesDirectoryExist path  -- check if directory exists.
    if(not isdir)                     
        then do handleWrong
    doOtherActions                    -- compiling ERROR here.
```

GHCi will complaint about identifiers , or do not exec the last line action after I add `else do` .

I think exception handling may work, but is it necessary in such common "check and do something" statements ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`if` in Haskell must always have a `then` and an `else`. So this will work:

```
action = do
    isdir <- doesDirectoryExist path
    if not isdir
        then handleWrong
        else return ()     -- i.e. do nothing
    doOtherActions
```

Equivalently, you can use `when` from Control.Monad:

```
action = do
    isdir <- doesDirectoryExist path
    when (not isdir) handleWrong
    doOtherActions
```

Control.Monad also has `unless`:

```
action = do
    isdir <- doesDirectoryExist path
    unless isdir handleWrong
    doOtherActions
```

---

Note that when you tried

```
action = do
    isdir <- doesDirectoryExist path
    if(not isdir)
        then do handleWrong
        else do
    doOtherActions
```

it was parsed as

```
action = do
    isdir <- doesDirectoryExist path
    if(not isdir)
        then do handleWrong
        else do doOtherActions
```

Comment: using [`when`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when) seems to be cleaner