# I keep getting solution.hs:9:1: parse error on input `main' . I am trying to print hello world n times recursively

Tags: haskell

```
hello_worlds n =    if n > 0
                    then do putStrLn "Hello World"                            
                            hello_worlds (n-1)              


main = do
   n <- readLn :: IO Int
   hello_worlds n
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because in Haskell the `if-then-else` structure, it [*requires an `else`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832828/haskell-do-nothing-io-or-if-without-else). This works:

```
hello_worlds n = if n > 0
                 then do putStrLn "Hello World"
                         hello_worlds (n-1)
                 else return ()

main = do
   n <- readLn :: IO Int
   hello_worlds n
```

Where the `return ()` can be seen as a *no-operation* statement.

This is mainly because I/O in Haskell is done using *Monads*: The `IO a`; with `a` the "return-type" of the Monad. Now evidently you do not return anything, but it could be possible that your I/O monad did (like `IO Int`), in which case both branches should return something.

Anyway, using an `if-then-else` block is by some (under some circumstances) considered to be [*bad*](https://wiki.haskell.org/If-then-else#What_is_so_bad_about_the_if-then-else_sugar.3F) as is the `do` statement as well.

---

You can replace this `if` statement (which is by some considered to be *un-Haskell*); and make it more declarative using:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM_)

main = do
   n <- readLn :: IO Int
   replicateM_ n $ putStrLn "Hello World"
```

because it makes it syntactically very clear that you are going to repeat (`replicate`) the `putStrLn "Hello World"` statement `n` times, whereas for the recursive approach it requires more thinking on how this works.

Comment: "do-blocks are bad, avoid them" is a very extreme position. There is a nuanced pedagogical argument about not using do-blocks at first when teaching beginners, but other than that do-blocks are fine and perfectly idiomatic Haskell. As for if-then-else, it is indeed the case that there usually are nicer alternatives, such as the one you show in the second half of the answer.

Comment: Here we go again... First of all, if you read carefully, it says "are considered by many..."; furthermore it links to a page of the Haskell wiki that explains it more carefully. If I would have to explain all in my course texts, they would be 3k+ pages instead of 300. The statement is a small footnote, it is not relevant to the question itself, but is relevant for people wanting to improve code hygiene and thus read the page behind the link.

Comment: I noticed that (though I would dispute the "many"). I only mentioned the majority opinion here to hopefully prevent the OP from avoiding do-blocks for no good reason. I wrote it as a comment because I didn't feel it justified a competing answer.

Comment: @duplode: modified... Happy?

Comment: It is certainly better, though I believe "do-blocks are bad" is such a minority stance it doesn't deserve a mention at all (the if-then-else part is fine). Please note that my comments (and, I presume, those of other [haskell] regulars as well) are not meant as nitpicking for the sake of it. We just care about lowering the likelihood of readers getting unnecessarily confused over details.

Comment: I don't see how monads have anything to do with it. The reason `if` requires an `else` is that `if` chooses between two expressions. It has to have an expression for the case where the condition holds and one for the case where it does not.